# Каким членом предложения является союзное слово СКОЛЬКО?

Tags: члены-предложения

> Если бы вы знали, сколько птиц прилетело в наши края!

Каким членом предложения здесь является слово **сколько**?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

*Сколько птиц* - цельное сочетание, является подлежащим. Ср.: *сто птиц*.